# Django filter on related field using annotate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to filter using annotate.

Here is my code:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Reader(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    blog= models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ReaderType)

class ReaderType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to get all the blog's that has at least 2 Reader of type `"male"`.
I have this code to get the blogs that have at least 2 Readers:

```
Blog.objects.annotate(reader_count=Count(reader)).filter(reader_count__gte=2)
```

How do I add the part that filter only the blogs that have at least 2 readers that their `type="male"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just filter on the reader type directly in your query:

```
posts_with_multiple_readers = (
    Blog.objects.filter(reader__type__name='male')
    .annotate(reader_count=Count('reader'))
    .filter(reader_count__gte=2)
)
```